# JavaFX setStyle with -fx-background-color paints only the edges of a TextArea

Tags: java, css, javafx

So, I have a dynamically created list of `TextArea`'s and I want to paint them depending on which `CheckBox` I select. Currently, it only colors the borders, but not the inside of the `TextArea`.

Here is my code:

```
if (cb.isSelected()) {
  ta.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#38ee00;");
}
if (cb2.isSelected()) {
  ta.setStyle("-fx-background-color:orangered;");
}
if (!cb2.isSelected() && !cb.isSelected()) {
  ta.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");
}
```

And here is the result that it brings:

[image]

If you need any other information, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to style the `.content` region that is a child of the `TextArea` ([see CSS Reference: TextArea - Substructure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area)).

You can get that node using `lookup`, but only after the skin is applied, which does not happen until layout. Then however you can do something like this:

```
Region content = (Region) ta.lookup(".content");
content.setStyle("-fx-background-color:orangered;");
```

An alternative would be using a CSS stylesheet and changing the class of the `TextArea` (provided only a limited number of colors is used):

```css
.text-area.color-orangered .content {
     -fx-background-color: orangered;
}

.text-area.color-white .content {
     -fx-background-color: white;
}

.text-area.color-green .content {
    ...
```

```
// remove old class for coloring
ta.getStyleClass().removeIf(s -> s.startsWith("color-"));

// add new class
ta.getStyleClass().add("color-orangered");
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS style class you are looking for is `.text-area .content`. You have several options to affect this style class, one possibility is to use [PseudoClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html) which makes you able to use CSS selectors.

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            // Add the CSS style class
            TextArea ta = new TextArea();
            ta.getStyleClass().add("my-text-area");


            ChoiceBox<String> cb = new ChoiceBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("green", "orangered"));
            cb.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                // On selection, change the pseudo class of the TextArea
                ta.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass(newValue), true);
                }
            });

            root.setCenter(ta);
            root.setBottom(cb);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*application.css*

```
.my-text-area:orangered .content {  
   -fx-background-color: orangered ;  
}  

.my-text-area:green .content {  
   -fx-background-color: green ;  
}
```